# Get function name as symbol (not as string) - C preprocessor

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Is there a way in **C** to get the function name on which I can use token-pasting
(I know `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__`, but they don't expand to name at pre-processing, 
and I do not want the name as a string).

I want to be able to do something like:
`prefix_ ## __func_name__` , so that, in a function by name `func1()`, I can access the
symbol `prefix_func1`

(maybe I can still use string, and then use `dlsym`, but want to know if there are
simpler alternatives in GCC, not worrying about portability).

Comment: Since the C preprocessor doesn't know what a function is (or what the boundaries of a function are), it is unlikely that there is any way to achieve what you seek using the preprocessor - except along the lines suggested by Jens.

Comment: Is it possible for you to pass the function name as argument? If so, you could just pass it as argument, even though it requires a "bit" more typing

Comment: @Shahbaz, I have a macro in the function, which will expand, and access the `prefix ## __func_name__`, if I can pass the name as arg, how can I access a new symbol ? - can you please elaborate.

Comment: A simple example. Let's say the macro is something like this: `#define CALL(x, y) do { /* do something with x and y */ prefix##__func_name__(); } while(0)` what I'm suggesting is something like this: `#define CALL(x, y, func_name) do { /* do something with x and y */ prefix##func_name(); } while(0)` then if you are inside function `f`, you write `CALL(x, y, f);` and if you are in function `g`, you write `CALL(x, y, g);` This way, you don't automatically discover the function name, but it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the function identifier a macro, as in

```
#define FUNC1 func1

void FUNC1(void)
{
   ...
}
```

and then use `FUNC1` for token pasting.